# AWS - MySQL / MariaDB Replication during maintenance process

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, mariadb, system-administration

I have a MariaDB Database on RDS (AWS).  We have some maintenance we need to do where several million records need to be updated across several tables -- no structure updates, just content.

I wondering what the best way is to accomplish this?  My thoughts are:

1) I don't want to interrupt user experience.  So it seems that running all this processing on production servers / DBs is a big nono

2) Because of the above, it makes sense to take a snapshot of the Production DB, and then run this process on a separate server.  Once finished, I can export that as a Snapshot, or just point the Production servers to that RDS instance

3) Finally, #2 above concerns me because if I take a Snapshot of Production to run these scripts on, we'll lose all Production that happens between the Snapshot, and the re-pointing of the servers to the newly update database

So my final thought was to replicate the Production DB, and have Production write to both... Then, run the scripts on the replica and point Production to the replica once the process finishes.

Seems logical, however, I'm not quite sure how to implement this on AWS.  Is this a reasonable solution or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: You're tinkering with fire.  What's the nature of the change that it can't be done on the production db due to disruption concerns?  Are these changes happening to tables that production writes to or only reads from?

Comment: It's updating several million records across 3-5 tables, based on data being pulled from a 3rd party API.  These are happening to tables that production both writes to and reads from

Comment: 3rd party API, can you even query that API fast enough for it to be a performance issue on the your db?

Comment: It seems maybe I'm presuming that this sort of work would disrupt production.  You're correct that it could only pull from the API at a certain rate.  I just figured we shouldn't slow down production at all.  But if it's common practice to potentially run this on production directly (after a test run on Staging) then that could work.

Comment: Once replication is set up, you need write only to the Master.